# Should the Famicom and NES tags be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I noticed that we have a [nes](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nes) tag but do not have a [famicom](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/famicom) tag.  I recently asked a Famicom question ([What is the Famicom "Pulse Line" of games? How many games are part of this line?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2273/621)) and used the [nes](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nes) tag instead of creating a new [famicom](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/famicom) tag.

1. Should we create a [famicom](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/famicom) tag for questions that are explicitly about the Japanese Family Computer and not the Nintendo Entertainment System released outside of Japan?
2. Should the [famicom](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/famicom) and [nes](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nes) tags be synonyms?

Answer (score 11):

The tags [famicom](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/famicom) and [nes](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nes) should be synonyms. They are two different versions of the same console; [zx-spectrum](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zx-spectrum) covers both the ZX (English) and Inves (Spanish) versions of this machine, for example.

Comment: A more apt comparison might be the ZX-81 and Timex-Sinclair 1000, both being essentially the same computer with slight variations for the two markets but with different names.

Comment: The Timex-Sinclair 1000 increased the memory of the ZX-81 by a whopping 200%.  But then again, we're talking about only adding 1 KiB of RAM for a total of 2 KiB.  LOL

Answer (score 0):

The tags [famicom](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/famicom) and [nes](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nes) should not be synonyms. These tags are both describing systems that are similar, but there is a separate [snes](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snes) tag for another similar system.

Comment: But the Famicom and NES are more closely related than the NES and SNES, those are two completely different systems, for which one would expect different tags.

Answer (score -4):

I think ideally you'd want three tags, one for things that cover both, and separate ones for things that are specific to each console so that you can easily search for information specific to one console or the other.  I'm not sure how workable that would be though.  Having [famicom](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/famicom), [nes](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nes), and [famicom-nes](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/famicom-nes), or something simialr, could easily get very confusing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could tag both if your question specifically call for both. I don't see the point of creating groups where we don't need them.

Comment: @nabulator You make a good point.  I think the search does allow you to use a logical AND to look for things that specifically apply to both.

Comment: Yes, you can search for posts with up to five tags in combination. (Since five tags is the maximum allowed by the system, you could probably add more, but it wouldn't really be meaningful to do so.) And while what you propose might work okay for something where only two variants existed, what about something with three or four variants? Don't forget that tags have a pretty firm maximum length limitation. It's better to use the tag wiki excerpt in combination with aliases for that kind of thing, IMO.